# Native logging module not printing to stdout in AzureML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use the standard `logging` module in my AzureML run but nothing gets printed out to stdout.

I tried following instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-enable-logging#python-native-logging-settings) but I have not been successful.

This is what I am running:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?')
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

stdout is generally redirected to a log file called "70_driver_log.txt", and with no configuration a local run submission should honor the basicConfig and you should see the output there.

You can fetch the logs from the UI or by streaming the logs in the SDK via run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

This is the link to the UI screenshot (but don't have the rep to post an image): [driver log in the ML studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwyjq.png)

Comment: I tried running that and it does not work for me. How did you submit the run? This is what I am doing: https://gist.github.com/alexandremuzio/8fccc13cad409860f83524e4dee11f1b

Comment: Interesting. Do you not even see the same log files or do they just not contain your output? I'm spinning up a GPU machine to try and eliminate that variable, but the two remaining differences I see are your Environment and the fact that it's a GPU run (again likely the environment).

I've tried a few different modes of submission and all seem to get me that output https://gist.github.com/akshaya-a/5428ee8577aeecf7f24233b1214b0421

Comment: Are you able to share more details about your custom image? Perhaps you can attempt a job using one of the standard base images and managed environments to help isolate the issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using GPU image,
myenv.docker.enabled = True
myenv.docker.base_image = azureml.core.runconfig.DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE

My guess is logging.basicConfig is called before my main script, so it is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Following piece of code worked for me. I guess, setting the handler is the key here.

```
import logging

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

More detailed response as well alternative approach about the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/14130).